# Covariance matrix and Gaussian i.i.d. random variables

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, covariance

I have a set $X = \left \{  X_i  |  i \in (1,n) \wedge  X_i \text{ is a random variable}    \right \} $

Does $\forall  i \in  (1,n ),  X_i \text{ follows a normal distribution}  $ implies that $\exists b \in \mathbb{R} \text{ s.t. covariance(X)} = bI_{n} \Leftrightarrow X_i \text{ are i.i.d.}$ ?

If so, what other commonly used distributions have this property?

I know that if x and y are two independent random variables, then their covariance is zero, but the converse is [not generally true](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Uncorrelatedness_and_independence).

Comment: You need $\{X_i\}$ to also be _jointly_ Gaussian for the diagonal covariance to imply i.i.d.

Comment: @remind: I think that [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent#An_asymmetric_example) is a counter-example.